# After changing Compiz configuration, I can't use account

Tags: compiz, 12.10

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I reset my Unity configuration?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/17610/how-do-i-reset-my-unity-configuration)

I think I have made some changes in Compiz and now I can't see anything on the screen when I log in with a user. For the other users everything is OK. Is there any possibility to reset to default compiz?
All I can do logged in as the user with problems is pressing ctrl-alt-F2, and then I have to log in a terminal.
I'm not at all a power user, so I apologies if my question is not very clear.
Thanks in advance

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I reset my Unity configuration?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/17610/how-do-i-reset-my-unity-configuration) and http://askubuntu.com/questions/17381/unity-doesnt-load-no-launcher-no-dash-appears

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can reset compiz by removing its configuration files. As you have already noticed, these files are stored per user. Log-in to the terminal (`ctrl-alt-fX`) and move the following directory

```
mv ~/.config/compiz-1 ~/.config/compiz-1-backup
```

Log out (`exit`) and log in via your GUI (`ctrl-alt-f7`). If all is fine, remove the backup directory.